# Wrong values are returned by my function in Python

Tags: python

I have the following code which yields the function

```
\eta_{k}=\frac{\epsilon*2^{k-1}}{\sin\theta}*(1-\cos\theta\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(1+\sqrt{1-\eta_{j}})
for k>1 and 

\eta_{1}=\epsilon*\tan(\frac{\theta}{2}).
```

Here `k` is an integer and `\epsilon` and `\theta` are floating point numbers.

Now, by definition `\eta_{k}` should not be above `2^{k-1}`, but, I am getting some unphysical values. For example:

```
eta(1.0000001, 3, np.pi/10000000)

Decimal('851903.0534777333315363710505')
```

What did I do wrong?

This is the code I wrote:

```py
from decimal import *
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

getcontext().prec = 28


def eta(epsilon, k, theta):
    if k == 1:
        numerator = Decimal(epsilon) * Decimal((Decimal(1) - Decimal(cos(theta))))
        denominator = Decimal(sin(theta))
        return Decimal(numerator / denominator)
    else:
        product_term = 1
        for j in range(1, k):
            eta_j = Decimal(eta(epsilon, j, theta))
            product_term *= Decimal((Decimal(1) + Decimal(sqrt(1 - eta_j))))
        numerator = Decimal(epsilon)*Decimal(2**(k-1))*(Decimal(1)-Decimal(cos (theta))*Decimal(product_term)/Decimal(2**(k-1)))
        denominator = Decimal(sin(theta)) 
        return numerator / denominator
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Also, I don't think that the Latex-style (?) math expressions really improve readability of your question...

Comment: On that note, I wish Stack Overflow supported LaTeX formatting like other sites do.

Comment: I am not sure how to phrase the question properly without the maths.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's a mistake in the calculation of the product term in the second equation. Specifically, the product term should include the square root of $\eta_j$ rather than $1-\eta_j$.

Comment: The product term includes square root of 1-eta_j as given by the definition of function eta_k.